# Исключительные права при разработке ПО

Tags: авторские-права, юридические-аспекты, фриланс

**Вопрос именно в том как переписать договор, чтоб заказчик мог пользоваться и распространять результат, а исполнитель не имел проблем с СПО и копипастой.**

Типовые договора содержат пункты

> 5. Права на ПО
>
> 5.1. Исключительные права по использованию ПО в целом и любой его части принадлежат Заказчику с момента создания ПО либо его
> соответствующей части.
>
> 5.2. Исполнитель не имеет права использовать ПО (его исходный текст либо объектный код) в целом и любую его часть кроме как для создания
> другого ПО Заказчика.
>
> 5.3. Личные неимущественные права на ПО принадлежат физическим лицам, трудом которых ПО создано.

Но тут получается конфликт с лицензиями СПО. Я же не могу передать исключительные права на то что созданно не мной.

Ещё создав одно приложение по этому договору я почти обязуюсь не создавать похожие проекты по этой формулировке - как это переформулировать? Я не собираюсь создавать проекты производные от этого, но некоторые операции, функции я не могу написать подругому в новых проектах. Например реализацию RFC (расчёт MPPE ключей) или какого-то типового АПИ (авторизацию JWT).

Для работы с современными фреймворками много копипастишь нелицензированного открытого кода.

Как переписать это  всё чтоб учесть использование СПО, копипасту и чтоб Заказчик мог потом это всё продать.

Comment: Конфликты с лицензиями не редкость. Сколько пришлось людям написать "своего" кода, чтобы не использовать один в один код под GPL.

Comment: *"`Ещё создав одно приложение по этому договору я обязуюсь не создавать похожие проекты"`* -- а вот на это вы зря подписываетесь (разве только уверены, что заказчик скоро отойдет в мир иной вместе со всеми договорами)

Comment: @avp немного не так выразился в этом предложении. переписал.

Comment: @eri, а можно из параграфа определений договора, если есть, термины: *ПО*, *[права по] использованию ПО* и *Личные неимущественные права на ПО*... если их нет, то договор составлен как-то странно т.к., например, «публикация исходных кодов» или «продажа оных третьим лицам» даже с очень большой натяжкой трудно назвать «использованием ПО»...

Answer (score 7):

**Дисклеймер:** Я не юрист. И то что написано далее не стоит трактовать, как юридический совет. Это только моё скромное мнение. Я не несу ни какой ответственности за любые последствия вызванные данным текстом, включая: увольнения, судебные разбирательства, ураганы, наводнения, бунты, революции, холивары, результаты выборов в США, конец света, непоправимые изменения в экосистемах связанные с бессмертием енотов и спонтанное самовозгорания, но не ограничиваясь оными.

---

> Но тут получается конфликт с лицензиями СПО. Я же не могу передать исключительные права на то что созданно не мной.

Это можно вписать одной строкой:

> 5.1. Исключительные права по использованию ПО в целом и любой его части**, созданной Исполнителем в рамках данного договора,** принадлежат Заказчику с момента создания ПО либо его
>   соответствующей части.

Ну и для верности:

> 5.2. Исполнитель не имеет права использовать ПО (его исходный текст либо объектный код) в целом и любую его часть**, исключительные права на использование которой принадлежат Заказчику,** кроме как для создания другого ПО Заказчика.

---

> Ещё создав одно приложение по этому договору я почти обязуюсь не создавать похожие проекты по этой формулировке - как это переформулировать?

Не сказал бы, что тут это есть. Здесь запрет на использование именно того кода, что является частью ПО, но на создание «кода делающего в точности тоже самое» ни какого запрета здесь нет.

> Я не собираюсь создавать проекты производные от этого, но некоторые операции, функции я не могу написать подругому в новых проектах. Например реализацию RFC (расчёт MPPE ключей) или какого-то типового АПИ (авторизацию JWT).

Если ты пишешь что-то подобное или с точно таким же функционалом **заново**, без непосредственного использования исходного кода, права на который переданы заказчику в рамках договора, то всё в порядке.

Если ты хочешь явно сохранить за собой право на повторное использование нескольких модулей, то стоит явно перечислить их в договоре как-то так:

> 5.1. Исключительные права по использованию ПО в целом и любой его части, созданной Исполнителем в рамках данного договора **за исключением перечисленных в Приложении 3**, принадлежат Заказчику с момента создания ПО либо его соответствующей части.
>
> **5.1.1 Заказчик получает право по использованию частей ПО, перечисленных в Приложении 3, но исполнитель сохраняет за собой аналогичные права применительно к оным.**
>
> ...
>
> #### Приложение 3. Список частей ПО, на которые Исполнитель сохраняет право на использование
>
> - Реализацию протоколов описанных в RFC-1149 с расширениями RFC-2325 и RFC-6214
> - Реализацию протокола HTCPCP, описанного в RFC-2325
> - …

---

ЗЫ: Если «Использование ПО» ни где не конкретизировано в договоре, то весь этот текст как-то странно звучит т.к. это довольно узкое понятие, но наглядности ради я ни где это выражение не изменял.

Answer (score 1):

Что касается свободно распространяемых библиотек - соблюдайте их лицензии - GPL не трогайте, к LGPL линкуйтесь динамически.

Что касается библиотек с другими лицензиями, типа MIT, Apache - они не являются кодом, написанным вами, так что и передавать эти библиотеки заказчику официально вы и не должны - вы не включаете коды этих библиотек в свой проект, а только указываете, где их взять и как собрать все в кучу.

Comment: Но ведь LGPL-библиотеки и вкомпиленный в бинарник MIT-код всё равно попадают под термин "ПО в целом", не? А про автора в показанной части договора ничего не сказано

Comment: webpack считается компиляцией?)

Comment: что делать с библиотеками я знаю, вопрос в том как переписать договор

Comment: @andreymal нет, не попадают. Потому что если так расширительно читать договор, дело дойдет до включения в состав ПО кусков венды. А что, неотъемлемая часть - включаем!

Comment: @gbg а где гарантии, что суд не будет так расширительно читать договор?) Обвинят в нарушении прав майкрософта и приехали :)

Comment: @gbg и кстати в GPL для "кусков венды" даже специальное исключение написано. Боюсь, это намекает на то, что без доп.пояснений даже американский суд будет читать договор именно что расширительно)

Comment: @andreymal это определяется не договором, а актом передачи сделанной работы Заказчику, в котором конкретно перечисляются файлы за авторством Исполнителя.

Comment: @gbg ещё раз, в приведённой части договора ничего не сказано про авторство - сказано про "ПО в целом", то есть вместе с "кусками венды". И неважно кто автор. И неважно что в акте написано.

Comment: В договоре где-то в другом месте должен быть пункт, конкретизирующий, что является этим самым ПО.